# Custom metric (Balanced accuracy) giving nan after first epoch

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network, metrics

I wrote a custom metric in tensorflow to implement Balanced Accuracy, but it gives nan after the first training epoch.
Here is my code:

```
class BalancedSparseCategoricalAccuracy(keras.metrics.Metric):

    def __init__(self, name='balanced_sparse_categorical_accuracy', **kwargs):
        super(BalancedSparseCategoricalAccuracy, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.correct_count = tf.Variable([0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
        self.total_count = tf.Variable([0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
        self.accuracy = 0.0
        self.quotient = tf.Variable([0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.])

    def reset_state(self):
        self.correct_count = tf.Variable([0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
        self.total_count = tf.Variable([0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
        self.quotient = tf.Variable([0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.])
        self.accuracy = 0.0

    def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
        pred_idx = tf.argmax(y_pred, axis=1, output_type=tf.int32)
        y_true=tf.reshape(y_true, tf.shape(pred_idx))
        y_true=tf.cast(y_true,tf.int32)

        def count_all(y_true):
            return tf.cast([ tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(tf.equal(y_true,i),tf.float32)) for i in range(0,7)],tf.int32)

        def count_match(y_true, y_pred):
             return tf.cast([ tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(tf.equal(y_true,i)&tf.equal(y_true,pred_idx),tf.float32)) for i in range(0,7) ],tf.int32)


        total_counts = count_all(y_true)
        tf.compat.v1.assign_add(self.total_count, total_counts)

        correct_counts = count_match(y_true, y_pred)
        tf.compat.v1.assign_add(self.correct_count, correct_counts)
        self.quotient = tf.cast(self.correct_count/tf.maximum(self.total_count,tf.constant(1)), tf.float32)
        print(self.quotient)
        #self.accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(self.correct_count/tf.maximum(self.total_count,1))
        #return self.accuracy

    def result(self):
        #self.accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(self.correct_count/tf.maximum(self.total_count,1))
        self.accuracy = tf.reduce_sum(tf.reduce_sum(self.quotient) / tf.cast(tf.math.count_nonzero(self.total_count),tf.float32))
        return self.accuracy
```

```
Epoch 1/40
31/31 [==============================] - 21s 354ms/step - loss: 13.7365 - balanced_sparse_categorical_accuracy_1: 0.4473 - accuracy: 0.5518 - val_loss: 17.3646 - val_balanced_sparse_categorical_accuracy_1: 0.3649 - val_accuracy: 0.4486
Epoch 2/40
31/31 [==============================] - 16s 333ms/step - loss: 13.7993 - balanced_sparse_categorical_accuracy_1: nan - accuracy: 0.5590 - val_loss: 16.8144 - val_balanced_sparse_categorical_accuracy_1: nan - val_accuracy: 0.4486
Epoch 3/40
31/31 [==============================] - 18s 361ms/step - loss: 13.2094 - balanced_sparse_categorical_accuracy_1: nan - accuracy: 0.5745 - val_loss: 16.6154 - val_balanced_sparse_categorical_accuracy_1: nan - val_accuracy: 0.4579
```

I tried to check if there was a division by zero, but that was not the case. I also checked on model predictions, and it gave the correct result:

```
predictions=model.predict(datav)

grd_truth=[]

for batch in datav:
    val=np.asarray(batch[1])
    grd_truth.extend(val)

acc = BalancedSparseCategoricalAccuracy()
acc.update_state(grd_truth, predictions)
acc.result()
```

Output:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.23611432>
```